# Mysql full text search exclude results

Tags: mysql, search, full-text-search

i have a question i do a full text search on my site and want exclude some results here is the code i use

```
SELECT *, MATCH(p_title, p_desc) AGAINST ('".$string."') AS score 
FROM posts 
WHERE MATCH(p_title, p_desc) AGAINST ('".$string."') 
ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 12
```

Now when I add for example WHERE id != 1 AND WHERE test != 1 to end of SELECT
this does not work, i googled but didn't find anything related to this. Is this at all possible?

I found a way with php

```
if($id != $list['id'] AND $list['test'] != 1) { 
// CODE
}
```

But this is not really what I want.
Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change

```
SELECT *, MATCH(p_title, p_desc) AGAINST ('".$string."') AS score     
FROM posts 
WHERE MATCH(p_title, p_desc) AGAINST ('".$string."') 
ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 12
```

To:

```
SELECT *, MATCH(p_title, p_desc) AGAINST ('".$string."') AS score     
FROM posts 
WHERE MATCH(p_title, p_desc) AGAINST ('".$string."') 
  AND (id <> 1) AND (test <> 1)
ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 12
```

It should work, of course you can't add an extra `WHERE` clause after the first one.
If you want to add extra items to filter on then you need to use `AND`'s.

Also note that doing a `SELECT *` will slow your query **way** down. 
Better list only the fields that you want to list, that will make your query much faster.
Make sure you have an index on p_title and p_desc to keep the speed acceptable.

If you want the search to be smarter and also return items related to `$string` you can change the code to:

```
SELECT *, MATCH(p_title, p_desc) AGAINST ('".$string."') AS score     
FROM posts 
WHERE MATCH(p_title, p_desc) AGAINST ('".$string."' WITH QUERY EXPANSION) 
  AND (id <> 1) AND (test <> 1)
ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 12
```

This will let MySQL do a second pass where terms in the found in the first pass are used to find extra items that do not match against $string, but that **do** match against the data found in the first pass.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-query-expansion.html

Comment: Thank you very much and thanks for the tip WITH QUERY EXPANSION